# Python - Search large list of keywords in a large unstructured data

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tagging

I have large bag of keywords that I want to search in large unstructured data and auto-tag this content.

First few steps that I took was to eliminate to pre-process the data like: removing stop words, punctuation, case-sentivity, check high-frequency words and delete them if I don't need. I adapted few things from this article: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/automated-keyword-extraction-from-articles-using-nlp-bfd864f41b34.

After the pre-processing, I am un-sure how I should be searching the keywords and how should I be auto-tagging them in a efficient way. Are there any good machine learning tutorials, algorithms, and/or Natural Language Processing that can do such task much better than what I am doing now?

Here is an example:
Bag of keywords:

```
keywords_to_search = ['Harry Potter','LOTR','Lord of the Rings','Secret Garden','Pinocchio'] # Some example, I have over 100K list of keywords to search
l1 = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl']
l2 = ['Pinocchio and Harry Potter is a famous children\'s book..','LOTR was written by J. R. R. Tolkien','Fordo Baggins is a character in Lord of the Rings Book Series.','blank']
df = pd.DataFrame({'some_col':l1,'text':l2})
```

Try:

```
df[df.text.str.contains('|'.join(keywords_to_search))] # for searching ... very slow for large unstructured texts
```

Looking for this:

```
some_col    text                                                                tags
abc         Pinocchio and Harry Potter is a famous children's book.             Pinocchio,Harry Potter
def         LOTR was written by J. R. R. Tolkien                                LOTR
ghi         Fordo Baggins is a character in Lord of the Ri...                   Lord of the Rings
```

Comment: How many entries/sentences per tag do you have? Are you looking for a faster ML, NLP alternative to string matching? Is your dataset one time or do you expect more sentences in the future that will need to be tagged using the same model developed during the training?

Comment: There are roughly 25 sentences per row, but once I do pre processing it should be smaller than 25 sentences. Yes, I am looking for ML or NLP route instead of regex way of searching on pandas dataframe. It's one time run to capture results and enhance if needed.

Comment: Not sure that a NLP/ML algorithm will be faster than regex in your particular case. May be someone else thinks of one but nothing comes to mind for me in your use case.

Comment: @AdnanS Okay. I think I will have to go regex route then.

Comment: just came across this that might help you as a faster alternative to regex https://flashtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: You can use aho corasick algorithm see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm